# Curl - Encode file as url query

Tags: json, curl

## Curl - Encode file as url query

I'm trying to send message to `Amazon SQS` queue with payload read from file using `curl`

So far I've got working curl to send message to queue but with harcoded value like:

```bash
curl --request POST \
     --url 'http://localhost:9324/queue/price-import?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=%7B%0A%09%22id%22%3A%20%22f23399af-a384-4ed3-bac0-386a01804d83%22%2C%0A%09%22de%22%3A%20%7B%0A%09%09%22price%22%3A%2010.59%0A%09%7D%2C%0A%09%22nl%22%3A%20%7B%0A%09%09%22price%22%3A%20107.99%0A%09%7D%2C%0A%09%22pl%22%3A%20%7B%0A%09%09%22price%22%3A%2012.15%0A%09%7D%0A%7D'
```

And payload I send is:

```json
{
    "id": "f23399af-a384-4ed3-bac0-386a01804d83",
    "de": {
        "price": 10.59
    },
    "nl": {
        "price": 107.99
    },
    "pl": {
        "price": 12.15
    }
}
```

**How can I modify this curl to omit harcoded value and instead put path to file with `.json` extension?**

### Desired output

```
curl --request POST \
     --data-urlencode http://localhost:9324/queue/price-import?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=@input.json
```

### What I already tried

- `curl --request POST -data-urlencode http://localhost:9324/queue/price-import?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=@input.json`
- `curl --request POST -data-urlencode input.json http://localhost:9324/queue/price-import`
- `curl --request POST -data-urlencode "sendbody@input.json" http://localhost:9324/queue/price-import`
- `curl --request POST --data-urlencode SendBody@input.json --url http://localhost:9324/queue/price-import?Action=SendMessage`

### Resources I found

- [Unix cURL POST to specific variable using contents from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489453/unix-curl-post-to-specific-variable-using-contents-from-a-file)
- [POSTing a file's contents with CURL](https://superuser.com/questions/543762/posting-a-files-contents-with-curl)
- [curl.1 the man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question based on this answer:

[How to urlencode data for curl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/how-to-urlencode-data-for-curl-command)

### This worked for me:

```bash
curl \
    --data-urlencode MessageBody@input.json \
    --data-urlencode "Action=SendMessage" \
    http://localhost:9324/queue/price-import
```

and my `input.json` file:

```json
{
    "id": "f23399af-a384-4ed3-bac0-386a01804d83",
    "de": {
        "price": 10.59
    },
    "nl": {
        "price": 107.99
    },
    "pl": {
        "price": 12.15
    }
}
```